# How to query dbpedia.org with sparql

Tags: sparql, opendata

I'm very new in OpenData and try to write a query in SPARQL.

My goal is to get data for following set of criteria:
 - Category: Home_automation
 - select all items from type "Thing"
 - with at least one entry in "is Product of"
 - that have a picture-url with a German description

I tried the following:

```
PREFIX cat:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT *
WHERE {
  cat:Home_automation skos:broader ?x
}
```

But now I don't know how to add the other filters to the where clause.
I tried to user broader:... to get the items, but I think that was the wrong direction.

I tested the queries with: `https://dbpedia.org/sparql`

The result should be:

```
|         (label)          | (url) 
|--------------------------|-----------------------------------
|"Kurzzeitwecker"@de       | urls to the picture of the device 
|"Staubsauger"@de          | -||-
|"Waschmaschine"@de        | -||-
|"Geschirrspülmaschine"@de | -||-
```

Does anyone have some tips please?

UPDATE: new query:

```
PREFIX cat: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?s ?label WHERE {
  ?s ?p cat:Home_automation .
  ?s rdf:type owl:Thing .
  ?s rdfs:label ?label
  FILTER (LANG(?label)='de')
}
order by ?p
```

Comment: You updated the query. Is that the solution now?

Comment: Not the full solution but it is a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear what you want. You must first know what exact related information dbpedia contains and how they are structured.

However, you can try discovering what types of relationships `cat:Home_automation` is involved in, thus, you may know better what you want.

I suggest starting by generic queries, to specify how `cat:Home_automation` occurs in dbpedia, then, you might be able to go more specific, and pose further queries.

A query to list triples where `cat:Home_automation`  is an subject:

```
PREFIX cat:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT ?p ?o WHERE {
   cat:Home_automation ?p ?o  
}
order by ?p
```

A query to list triples where `cat:Home_automation`  is an object:

```
PREFIX cat:  <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Category:>
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>

SELECT ?s ?p WHERE {
   ?s ?p cat:Home_automation 
}
order by ?p
```

check the results, see what is interesting for you, and then continue with further queries.

Comment: Yes, that's my problem to It's an exercise for university and nobody in our team knows how to solve the task. I've added the required result above.

Your second query looks quite good, how can I filter the ?s so that i get only entries of type "Thing"?
Thanks for help.

Comment: Ok after a few tries a got the right result. Thank you for your tip with the "cat:Home_automation" as object.